# Selecting elements of n inputs in c without using arrays

Tags: c, input, integer, output, sequence

Given a sequence of integers as input I need to be able to select specific integers of the sequence so that I can execute various arithmetic operations between them.

For example, given this input I want to know the sum of the third and the last integer of the sequence.
EDIT: in the example it would be the sum of 7 and 9

3

1

7

4

9

The condition I have to follow is that I don't use arrays so I can't give every integer an index.
Also I can't know in advance how many integers there will be in the sequence so I can't create an input that determine the number of integers.

To read the inputs I thought of using this loop with a scanf condition:

```
 while (scanf("%d", &i) == 1);
```

The thing I'm stuck in is how to select the third and the last integers; if it was something like finding the sum of the odd integers I would just put a condition like this:

```
if (i%2 != 0)
{
   sum = sum + i;
   i++;
}
```

Most examples are solved using a for lopp but they either have the number of inputs declared or the inputs are just consecutive integers.
Any suggestion on how can I solve this problem?

Comment: So what does the input mean exactly. 3 mean third? Third in the following sequence or overall third? So the input is a sequence of integers where the first determine which one should be added to the last one?

Comment: In the example the third integer would be the integer 7 and the last  the integer 9

Comment: @Mizzet do you know concepts of linked lists or stacks?

Comment: But what if the sequence is 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 ? Since you mentioned "can't know in advance how many integers" therefore it can be any sequence.  So what is the **general** rule for the calculation which should be carried out on the input? Always the third and the last?

Comment: @Eraklon yes it can be any sequence. In your example it would be the sum of 3 and 7

Comment: @Melon no haven't done structures yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can mix a simple for loop with your scanf condition so you can associate an index to each number and memorize numbers needed to compute your operation (including the last).

Here is an example:

```c
int i, value;
int sum = 0;
int lastValue = 0;
for(i=1 ; scanf("%d", &value) == 1 ; ++i)
{
    if(i == 3) /* select the third element */
        sum += value;
    lastValue = value; /* memorize the last element so far to compute it later */
}
sum += lastValue; /* assume that there is at least one value in the sequence */
```